# Linking Data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

What is the easiest way to do the following:

I have a list with 4 columns (customer name, invoice number, invoice date, invoice amount) and in another spread sheet I want to enter the invoice number ONLY and make Excel copy the related information (customer name, invoice date and invoice amount)

how can I link the 2 workbooks together and make Excel do this for me by just entering the invoice number?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make the column **Invoice Number** the first column in your array, for example in Sheet1 the 4 columns should be:
**Invoice Number** (1) then **Customer Name** (2) then **Invoice Date** (3) then **Invoice Amount** (4) with the data below it making the array **A2:D5** in Book1
In Book2 write in A1 the Invoice Number that you want the related informations,
In B1 write :
`=VLOOKUP(A1,'[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$D$5,2,FALSE)` for Customer Name
In C1
`=VLOOKUP(A1,'[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$D$5,3,FALSE)` for Invoice Date and format as Date
In D1 `=VLOOKUP(A1,'[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$D$5,4,FALSE)` for Invoice Amount

Book1.xlsx is the name of the **open book** where your array information is located but if the book is closed and you want to extract the information you have to write the full path like the following:
`=VLOOKUP(A1,'C:\Users\Documents\example\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$D$5,2,FALSE)`

Comment: SuperSam,, That was Super amazing!

Comment: If everything is like you want kindly accept the reply